# CSS markup is missing after I change theme of subsite

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, theme

I was just making a new subsite, and the very first thing I usually do is set the theme to match that of the parent. In my case this is a custom theme named CustomTheme. I selected it and applied it and BAM. The whole layout and style of the subsite was messed up. And the strange thing is that this now seems to happen with ALL the themes, all but the default one. 
I did not change anything to the main site or to the site collection, I just created a new subsite. And even now when I make another subsite elsewere in the site collection, this new subsite also suffers from the issue.

So what it comes to is that I can't apply any other theme than the default one. Does anyone perhaps know what may have caused this? I'm running SharePoint Foundation 2010 and make all changes in either browser or in SharePoint Designer 2010. Host OS is Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sometimes run into the issue where the Master Page and custom CSS setting in subsites 'stick' - where they appear to be set properly but clearly aren't.  In order to fix those cases, you have to set the master page and the CSS link to something other than what you want, save the change then go back in and change it to inherit again.  I know this is related to the fact that SharePoint has two settings for these values and they somehow get out of sync but haven't had the time and opportunity to investigate it further